# How can I monitor the lambda invocation metrics in cloudwatch?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I have created a lambda function in AWS then add a trigger event from `cloudwatch` which trigger the lambda function every minute. But I couldn't see the lambda function is called every minute from `Monitoring` view of lambda after running it for a whole night.

Below is the screenshot of `Invocation` metric:

[image]

You can see that the maximum number of invocations is only 5 during the last hour.

And below screenshot is the lambda configuration which has `cloudwatch event` as its trigger source.

[image]

The definition in `cloudwatch event` is shown below screenshot. It links to my lambda function and its status is `Enabled`. I don't understand why the `Invocations` is not showing the right number of calling. Or do I mis-understand anything here? Or isn't my lambda function called?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Your lambda is being called correctly.**  The invocation graph shows the number of calls per 5 minutes.  The graph is showing that there are 5 invocations every 5 minutes, which means that your lambda is being called once every minute.

You can also take a look at the [lambda's cloudwatch logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-logs.html) to check if your function is being called correctly.

Comment: how do you know it shows `The invocation graph shows the number of calls per 5 minutes.` Is the 5 minutes a default setting on AWS?

Comment: If you're looking at this graph on the Lambda Monitoring tab, you can hover the line and see what the timestamps are on each datapoint (they will be 5 min apart). You can gain more control over the dashboard by moving it to CloudWatch Dashboards (there is a button to move it), there you can edit the graphs and change periods. Look at the pricing for dashboards if you decide to do that: https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/

Comment: As @UnkindnessofDatapoints properly mentioned, if you hover your mouse over the line you can see in the popup that each point on the graph is 5 minutes apart from one another.